# TeamCity and Rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, teamcity

Can anyone please point me to a documentation/demo on how to deploy a Ruby on Rails web app using Teamcity once build passed? The scenario is to: deploy the web app, by starting the web server on the build machine and then firing UI functional tests. (Note: Would like to know if all these steps can be automated using Teamcity?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Capistrano to deploy with TeamCity. Capistrano is great for deploying Rails apps, you can automate it reasonably easily so that TeamCity simply fires your Capistrano job.

More on Capistrano https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/

You probably want to use RVM with TC too.

Comment: Other than the github link to capitstrano's page, the rest of the links are broken...